# The difference between the X-Forwarded-For header and the Via header

Tags: proxy, http-headers, http-via-header

I am developing a proxy and have been investigating the headers by looking at the [W3 Guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/ct-guidelines/). My proxy adds the incoming REMOTE-ADDR to the X-FORWARDED-FOR header but I'm not sure how this compares with the Via header. I've looked on the wikipedia page and this lists

```
Via: 1.0 fred, 1.1 example.com (Apache/1.1)
```

but I have not found any instructions as to how this should be built up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're both headers that indicate that content has passed through proxy, and it's fine to include both headers.

The `Via` header is for protocol version (so you know if connection has been downgraded at any point), hostname of proxy and optional product/version of the proxy (like `User-Agent` of the proxy). It's just for information/debugging or identifying and working around buggy proxies (e.g. if you wanted to use request pipelining you'd watch that space).

`XFF` is for forwarding original IP of the client to the server. If the server trusts the proxy (or chain of proxies) it can use it instead of connection's IP.

Comment: So if I called my proxy MyProxy and it was version 1.0 but this had passed through the example above it would be Via: 1.0 fred, 1.1 example.com (Apache/1.1), 1.0 MyProxy

Comment: @MrWilde Sorry, I forgot that that field carries other information as well. So it'd be `Via: …, 1.1 mrwildesserver (MyProxy/1.0)` (where 1.1 is HTTP version you support).